# The eighteen faced goddess

Tags: shiva, goddess, vedic-gods, nava-durga, durga-saptasati

I was drawing a comparison between a local goddess from Kullu in Himalaya, one from mainstream Hinduism. Could you help me with it? Here's the information the temple priest gave me, and here I quote,

> She is the eighteen faced Mahakali, the sister of Parvati, and of Lord Vishnu. Upon their marriage (Lord Shiva and Parvati), she got angry with lord Shiva teasing her, and vowed to never look at him.

Could you help :/

Comment: Could you also tell us the name of the temple? That would help us trace down the reference.

Comment: Well, as far as I could track, it is called, "Devi Rupasna Temple - Dhargan" though the actual temple is a few miles from there, am adding a link to the Google maps here, :D https://www.google.com/search?q=devi+rupasna+dhargan&oq=devi+rupasna+dhargan&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.7841j0j4&client=ms-android-xiaomi&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Interesting there is no concrete reference I could find about devi Rupasana. I'll dig more. Thanks for sharing the little information.